# Remove one newline?

Tags: regex

I am using `body.replace(/\r?\n((?!\r?\n)|(?=\r?\n\r?\n\r?\n))/g,'')`, to replace newlines, the problem is it removes them all, in case there are two or more newlines one after another i want to keep them since it represent a paragraph.

**for example :**

> Money causes teenagers to feel stress.
> It makes them feel bad about themselves and envy other people.
> My friend, for instance, lives with her family and has to share a room with her sister,
> who is very cute and intelligent.
>
> This girl wishes she could have her own room and have a lot of stuff,
> but she can’t have these things because her family doesn’t have much money.
> Her family’s income is pretty low because her father is old and doesn’t go to work.

**I want it to be like :**

> Money causes teenagers to feel stress. It makes them feel bad about themselves and envy other people. My friend, for instance, lives with her family and has to share a room with her sister, who is very cute and intelligent.
>
> This girl wishes she could have her own room and have a lot of stuff, but she can’t have these things because her family doesn’t have much money. Her family’s income is pretty low because her father is old and doesn’t go to work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need such a complex regex. Those look-arounds are really not needed.

You can simply use this:

```
body.replace(/(\r|\n|\r\n){1,}/g,'$1');
```

`$1` is back-reference. Replace it with `\1` if it is used in your regex engine.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this

```
body.replace(/([^\n])(?:\r?\n)(?=[^\n])/g,"$1");
```